# Codeigniter with bootstrap x-editable and multiple inputs

Tags: codeigniter, input, x-editable

i been trying to figure out how to do this but i couldn't find any solution or answer about it.
I'm working with x-editable for bootstrap and codeigniter and the issue that is driving me crazy is that i dont know how to integrate x-editable with CI when i have more than one input related to the same "pk" in the same page.

For example, i have materials that have a single "name" and "comment". When i'm trying to edit a single value (for example, the "name" of a material), the x-editable plugin sends a value that i capture in my backend and then send to a model and into de database. 
That works great, but the deal is that when i edit the column "name" in my db the column "comment" is changed with the "name" value at the same time, instead of keeping in the actual value.

Init x-editable plugin

```
$('.inline-editable').editable({
    selector: 'a.editable-click',
    type: 'text',
    url: 'admin/material/update/',
    title: 'Click para editar',
});
```

This are the x-editable inputs

```
<tr class="entity-row row-fluid inline-editable" data-section="material" data-pk="1">
    <td>
        <a  href="#" id="name-12" class="entity-material editable-click" data-name="name" data-type="text">Name of the material</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="material-12" class="entity-material-comment editable-click" data-name="comment" data-type="textarea">This is the comment of the material</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Backend controller method

```
public function update() {
$this->db_data['id'] = $this->input->post('pk');
    $this->db_data['name_value'] = $this->input->post('value'); // Should be the name $value
    $this->db_data['comment_value'] = $this->input->post('value'); // This should be the comment $value

    // I try to capture this values for the db columns name to be edited
    // But i know this can't be possible because 
    // they have the same $_POST variable name.
    $this->db_data['db_column_name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $this->db_data['db_column_comment'] = $this->input->post('name');

    $this->entity_model->update_entity($this->db_table, $this->db_data);
}
```

Backend model method

```
function update_entity($table, $data) {
    $this->table = $table;

    $query .= $this->db->set($data['db_column_name'], $data['name_value']);
    $query .= $this->db->set($data['db_column_comment'], $data['comment_value']);
    $query .= $this->db->where($this->table.'.id', $data['id']);
    $query .= $this->db->update($this->table);
}
```

I hope you could understand this because english it's not my native language
Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually get as your `POST` values in the `update()` method? Can you do a `print_r($_POST);` on that update method and update the question?

Comment: I don't know how to print_r(post values) when the values were send by ajax. Beyond that i put a print_r($_POST) on the update() method but it returns an empty array()

Comment: That means nothing is posted to the method. If you use Firebug in Firefox, you can inspect ajax requests and see what values are posted to the given URI. Seems to be an issue on the front-end.